# display json data from api in html angular 8

Tags: javascript, angular, api

Trying to display data from this api. It is showing up in the console as a single object in an array.

calling api in service

```
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import { HttpClient } from "@angular/common/http";

@Injectable({
  providedIn: "root",
})
export class VillagersService {
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

  url = `http://acnhapi.com/v1/villagers/`;

  getVillagers() {
    return this.http.get(this.url);
  }
}
```

component where i want to put objects from api into an array

```
import { Component, OnInit } from "@angular/core";
import { VillagersService } from "src/app/services/villagers.service";

@Component({
  selector: "app-main",
  templateUrl: "./main.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./main.component.css"],
})
export class MainComponent implements OnInit {
  villagers: any = [];
  constructor(private villagerService: VillagersService) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.villagerService.getVillagers().subscribe((data: any) => {
      this.villagers.push(data);

      console.log(this.villagers);
    });
  }
}
```

html is currently displaying one list item that reads [object, Object]

```
<p>main works!</p>
<h1>Villagers</h1>
<div *ngFor="let villager of villagers">
  <ul>
    <li>{{ villager }}</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

I'm not sure how I can separate each of the objects and display as a list

Comment: Is the API returning an array? If so, you should be adding to the `villagers` array like this: `this.villagers.push(...data);`

Answer (score 2):

It appears the response from the API (http://acnhapi.com/v1/villagers/) is one single object with multiple nested objects. In this case you could try to use the [`keyvalue`](https://angular.io/api/common/KeyValuePipe) pipe.

Controller

```js
export class MainComponent implements OnInit {
  villagers: any;
  constructor(private villagerService: VillagersService) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.villagerService.getVillagers().subscribe((data: any) => {
      this.villagers = data;
    });
  }
}
```

Template

```html
<ng-container *ngFor="let ant of villagers | keyvalue">
  {{ ant.key }}
  <ng-container *ngFor="let prop of ant.value | keyvalue">
    <ng-container *ngIf="prop.key !== 'name'; else nameBlock">
      {{ prop.key }} - {{ prop.value }}
    </ng-container>
    <ng-template #nameBlock>
      <ng-container *ngFor="let name of prop.value | keyvalue">
        {{ name.key }} - {{ name.value }}
      </ng-container>
    </ng-template>
  </ng-container>
</ng-container>
```